# does anybody know the apns messages used for standard things - like beep

Tags: iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

Apples me app can make a phone beep or display a message. I assume this is done via APNS talking to ios directly. Does anybody know what these messages are (Apple doesnt seem to document them)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a server development question... but either case, when using PHP, you just tag a sound key into an array which you pass to an Apple APNS server. Here is the tutorial I used a while ago:
[APNS tutorial](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

You'll notice the sound option in the payload array:

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is the alert text', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
```

Comment: but thats a message for my app (isnt it); i dont have an app on the device but I do have an APNS cert. Maybe my question is meaningless

Comment: Messeges are application specific. You need to have an app on the device to receive APNS.